# What is a cryptic call stack?

Tags: c++, callstack

I have taken programming classes before but never had I heard about a cryptic call stack. What is it?

Comment: It's like this question, no-one knows what it means.

Comment: Me neither. Seems like just colloquial English for "call stack that's difficult to understand".

Comment: Where did you hear about it? Provide the reference and take time to frame your question in clear and concise manner or this will get closed soon as not a real Q.Also, note that the C++ standard doesn't talk of any *cryptic callstack* as such.

Comment: Maybe a call stack that resulted from heavy inlining and optimizations? Or one that's been smashed?

Comment: My boss mentioned it at work... was wondering if any of you guys could help because I tried googling but it seems nothing has been of much help..

Comment: You should ask your boss what does he mean exactly when he says *cryptic callstack*, You can just say it is not a standard term and So you are not aware of it.

Comment: I think your boss was just trying to say that the call stack made it difficult to decipher what was going on in the application, it's not a technical term. An _equivocally abstruse callstack_ on the other hand..

Comment: Alrighty. I shall do that. Was gonna explore the interwebs at first before I asked him since I'm kind of new but now that many of you say it's not an actual technical term, I suppose googling will just waste my time. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming it's referring to a call stack that is outside of your code or where stack frames are missing. Breaking execution in a thread operated by the OS (`ntdll.dll` anyone?), or a crash resulting from undefined behavior (that happens outside your code) can lead to call stacks that you usually can't make sense of.